# Excel VBA Rows.Count reference for a loop

Tags: vba, excel

I need to pull a range of data from a sheet where the top 16 rows will always be the same but the data below will vary. I can find the starting cell with this

```
Sheets("AA").Next.Select
Range("A17").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(2, 2).Select
```

and then I want to count the cells using (starting cell selected above) to end of cells containing data. I have tried this

```
Range(Selection, Range(Selection.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
```

and all kinds of variations on it but cannot seem to make it work. I need to be able refer back to both the start cell and the number of rows to pull data from that cell down to the last cell using a loop (another topic I will probably ask questions on when I get that far)

Can someone help?

Comment: You need to find the `LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.count, ActiveColumn).End(xlUp).row` Then if you subtract the first 16 from that it will be the number of rows.

Comment: I wish I understood your needs. Could you be more descriptive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your explanation as to *why* you are trying to do this makes it appear you are placing more work on yourself than you need to.

Let's create a couple functions.

The first function we will call `nextBlankCell`, which will automatically grab the last cell before an empty range. In your case, we can even use your selection to determine this - which we will do in our next function.

### nextBlankCell Function

```
Function nextBlankCell(ByVal startRng As Range) As Range
    Set nextBlankCell = startRng.End(xlDown)
End Function
```

Next, let's create a function that will automatically set your entire range for you. In this case, it will be the range from your current selection to the last row containing data that we get from using the above function.

### getRngDownwards Function

```
Function getRngDownwards() As Range

    Dim celStart As Range, celEnd As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Set celStart = Selection
    Set ws = celStart.Parent
    Set celEnd = nextBlankCell(celStart)
    Set getRngDownwards = ws.Range(celStart, celEnd)

End Function
```

In the above function, we have two ranges `celStart` and `celEnd`. `celStart` is simply your current selection. I always prefer to immediately **set** your selection to a static range if you must use `Selection` *(most cases it’s **not** necessary)*.

`celEnd` is the range that will contain the last used cell in your column.

We also determine the worksheet `ws` by using the selection's parent object. *Protip: We avoided `ActiveSheet`!*

Now you can put it to the test:

```
Sub test()

    ' This test shows you the address of the range
    MsgBox getRngDownwards.Address

    ' This test visually shows you the range
    getRngDownwards.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: This is helpful. I can see where it is going. However, I don't want to go all the way to the last row of the sheet. I want to go down to the last non-blank cell in that column and then with the next batch of data I pull, I want to skip down to the next non-blank cell and grab that starting cell down to the next non-blank cell and so on.